# Absence of map_public_ip_on_launch optional attribute in my resource

Tags: terraform

If I simply don't include "map_public_ip_on_launch" attribute in my resource, terraform won't try to map one at all as its an optional parameter, or do I need to specify it's time the flag of this parameter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are referring to the attribute for [`aws_subnet`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/subnet.html#map_public_ip_on_launch). This sets the default behavior for instances launched in that subnet. If you don't specify it defaults to `false`. However, you can still specify [`associate_public_ip_address`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#associate_public_ip_address) on an [`aws_instance`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html) resource as `true` and it will receive a public address regardless of if the subnet has a default of false.

Comment: Yes I am referring in aws_subnet resource. Thanks for the explanation.